# Drawing a tetrahedron with triangles

Tags: three.js

Trying to create a tetrahedron with three triangles. I could'nt orient faces. Here is the code :

HTML

```html
<div id="myid"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```js
const divid = document.getElementById("myid");

let facesVectors = [ // triangles vertices
 [0, 0, 0], 
 [-1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0],
 ]

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  1,
  1000
);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

divid.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = 2.5;

// equilateral triangle template
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-0.48, 0, 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0.48, 0, 0))
geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0.72, 0))
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2))

let material, face, i
let faces = []
for (i = 0; i < facesVectors.length; i++) {
  material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00FF00, side: THREE.DoubleSide })
  face = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
  face.position.set(facesVectors[i][0], facesVectors[i][1], facesVectors[i][2])
  if (i === 1) {
    face.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2)
  } else if (i === 2) {
    face.rotation.x = -(Math.PI / 2)
  }
  faces.push(face)
  scene.add(face)
}

let animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  faces.forEach((face)=>{
    face.rotation.x += 0.005;
    face.rotation.y += 0.01;
  })
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

demo : https://codepen.io/jeffprod/pen/GRJGYoQ

How to rotate triangles 1 and 2 so that i get a tetrahedron ? Is there a simplest way to do ?
Of course i don't want to use the TetrahedronBufferGeomety because i will need to manage faces colors and a lot of other triangles oriented differently.

Comment: It's impossible to compose a tetrahedron with just three triangles. It always has four. BTW: You can manage face colors with `TetrahedronBufferGeomety` since it's already an non-indexed geometry.

Comment: well i meant a pyramid without base. I don't need 4 faces. I want an empty one.

Comment: Isn't it easier to take a standard TetrahedronGeometry and remove one of the faces? :s

Answer (score 2):

Based on this [forum topic](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/tetrahedron-non-indexed-buffer-geometry/12542?u=prisoner849). Just commented out two lines for faces and uvs:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, -1, 2);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// tetrahedron
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var pts = [ // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Coordinates_for_a_regular_tetrahedron
  new THREE.Vector3(Math.sqrt(8 / 9), 0, -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2 / 9), Math.sqrt(2 / 3), -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(-Math.sqrt(2 / 9), -Math.sqrt(2 / 3), -(1 / 3)),
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
];

var faces = [ // triangle soup
  //pts[0].clone(), pts[2].clone(), pts[1].clone(),
  pts[0].clone(), pts[1].clone(), pts[3].clone(),
  pts[1].clone(), pts[2].clone(), pts[3].clone(),
  pts[2].clone(), pts[0].clone(), pts[3].clone()
];

var geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(faces);
geom.rotateX(-Math.PI * 0.5);
geom.computeVertexNormals();

geom.setAttribute("uv", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute([ // UVs
  //0.5, 1, 0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1,
  0.06698729810778059, 0.2500000000000001, 0.9330127018922194, 0.2500000000000001, 0.5, 1
], 2));
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var tetrahedron = new THREE.Mesh(geom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg"),
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
}));

scene.add(tetrahedron);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```